# Php relative root

Tags: php, require

I have a file structure looking like this:

```
root/
└── milk/
    ├── farmer1/
    │   ├── a/
    │   │   └── aa/
    │   │       └── file1.php
    │   ├── b/
    │   │   └── file2.php
    │   └── file3.php
    ├── farmer2
    └── farmer3
```

**farmer2** and **farmer3** have the exact same subdirectories and files as farmer1 has.

My `file2.php` includes `file3`. When i now want to include file2 in file1 the relativ path which includes `file3` in `file2` is of course totally wrong (No such file or directory error).
I can't use absolute paths because there are multiple farmers and I don't want to manually change each path for other farmers. I already tried to define a "root" var in a config.php but I have the same problem then when I try to include config.php. And I do not own the server, so no root access if this is important.

How could this be done?

Comment: did you try to include it using `include('../file.php');`

Comment: yes i did but the path is still completly wrong when I include file2 in file1

Comment: if you want to include a file relative to the file that the include appears within use `include(__DIR__."/relative/path/to/file.php");`

Comment: To follow on from @Orangepill, also you can do `include dirname(__FILE__) . "/relative/path/to/file.php";` which is pretty much the same thing, but you can replace `__FILE__` with any path to file and it will give you the directory for it.

Comment: `__DIR__` would possibly be the solution if the server didn't run php 4.2.

I'll try it with `__FILE__`.

Comment: @user2078468: You're joking?! server is running 4.2... really? It was EOL-ed back in 2002 ([wiki: 2002-09-06](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)). Christ, _upgrade_

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem if it was my server it would be running 5.5.3 but yeah I guess I have to deal with it..

Comment: @ninty9notout your methode works just perfectly thanks (:

Comment: I'll post it as an answer along with @Orangepill's comment too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to include a file relative to the file that the include appears within use `include(__DIR__."/relative/path/to/file.php");` - @Orangepill in the comments above

You can do: `include dirname(__FILE__) . "/relative/path/to/file.php";`

Which is pretty much the same thing, but you can replace `__FILE__` with any path to file and it will give you the directory for it.